# How to split a .doc into two files per speaker

Tags: parsing, split, ms-word

New to this. . . but have a simple question

How can I batch convert .doc files to split each file into 2 new .doc files per speaker?

I have conversational data and I want to have split the original conversation into two new files that will have all the utterances from Speaker A in one files and all the utterances in Speaker B in another.  I have about 250 files and would like to batch convert and split each conversation per speaker so that I have 2 files for every 1.

Example:

```
Speaker A: hey what's up
Speaker B: just getting ready for Mardi Gras!
Speaker A: it's going to be so much fun!
Speaker B: I'm going to get some beads!
```

File 1:

```
hey what's up
it's going to be so much fun!
```

File 2:

```
just getting ready for Mardi Gras!
I'm going to get some beads!
```

Comment: If these files are `.doc` files formatted according to `Word`, then you'd need to convert them to `.txt` to process them in batch. Or they may be pure text files simply labelled `*.doc` - please clarify.

Comment: @Magoo You can also batch-process with Windows tools, maybe Powershell and whatnot...

Comment: @Robert: Ah yes! Marvellous utility that `whatnot`. OP doesn't seem to have placed a restriction on how it's to be processed, so off you go... I'll wait for clarification. And I've got to cut the grass today. (OK - anything to put *that* off...

Comment: @Magoo I can batch convert them to .txt files just fine--- if that makes it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Challenge: accepted, just so I could check out the methods offered by the `Word.Application` COM object.  In the future, please show some code where you've attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Anyway, here's a batch + PowerShell polyglot script that'll do what you want.  Hopefully the comments will adequately explain how it works.  Save it with either a .bat or a .ps1 extension, whichever you prefer.  The output is in .txt, not .doc.

```perl
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

rem # reopen this script with powershell
powershell -noprofile -noninteractive "iex (gc \"%~f0\" | out-string)"

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin powershell #>

$word = new-object -COM Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$word.DisplayAlerts = $false

# For each Word document...
gci *.doc,*.docx | %{

    # init speakers hash table for this document
    $speakers = @{}

    write-host ("Reading {0}... " -f $_.Name) -f magenta -nonewline
    # args: documentsObject.Open(filename, confirm conversions, read-only)
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName, $false, $true)

    # For each paragraph in the document...
    $doc.Paragraphs | %{
        $line = $_.Range.Text -split ':\s*'

        # If the hashtable doesn't know this speaker, init the speaker
        if (-not $speakers[$line[0]]) { $speakers[$line[0]] = @() }

        # Append the current paragraph to the speaker.
        $speakers[$line[0]] += $line[1..($line.length - 1)] -join ': '
    }

    $doc.Close()
    write-host "Done." -f magenta

    # get the basename of the current Word doc as a prefix for output files
    $base = $_.BaseName

    # For each speaker in the $speakers hash table
    $speakers.keys | %{
        write-host "Writing $base $_.txt" -f green
        $speakers[$_] | out-file "$base $_.txt"
    }
}

$word.Quit()
[void]([Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word))
```

Comment: This is amazing!  Thank you so much.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\q*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filepfx=%%~nxa"
 SET "lastspeaker="
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=:" %%d IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO (
  SET "speaker=%%d"
  SET "line=%%e"
  CALL :process
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
 IF NOT DEFINED line (SET "line=%speaker%") ELSE SET "lastspeaker=%speaker%"
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%s IN ("%line%") DO >>"%destdir%\%filepfx%-%lastspeaker%" echo(%%s
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35122036.txt` containing your data for my testing.

If the files are straight `.txt` files, with the usual warnings about the usual suspects in the contents (ie - symbols like `%` but such are rarely used in dialogue) then the above should work.

Explanation:

First set `sourcedir` and `destdir` to point to the appropriate directories.

Next perform a directory-scan, assigning each filename in turn to `%%a`. I used a filemask of `q*.txt` to filter only those `.txt` files starting with `q`. You should probably omit the `q`.

With each filename, set `filepfx` to the name and extension of `%%a` Omit the `x` to use simply the file name part.

Initialise `lastspeaker`, then read each line from the file, assigning the speaker name to `%%d` and the text to `%%e`, using `:` as the delimiter. Assign these two parts to `speaker` and `line` and call the subroutine.

The subroutine `:process`

First checks whether `line` has been set. If there was no colon in the line read from the sourcefile, `line` will not be defined, so set `line` from `speaker`. If `line` is defined, set `lastspeaker` from `speaker`.

(OK - a bit of negative logic there - I'd switch the condition if I was really worried, but it'll work as-is)

Next use `tokens=*` to remove leading spaces from `line` and assign the result to `%%s`. construct the destination filename from the destination directory, the filename being processed and the last speakername.

Comment: I was able to get this to work too!  Thank you both!